# Push object to EmberJS Data Store

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I would like to know how to push record to the Ember Data Store without using the adapter.

For now every time I'm using `this.store.push({type: type, data: data})` the store sets the flag `hasDirtyAttributes` to true.

As workaround I'm using `this.store.findRecord(type, id);` to get the record updated from the server but I don't need that because the `data` I have already came from the server.

Comment: have you tried store.pushPayload  ?http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_pushPayload

Comment: Perfect it worked. You can answer my question if you care about Reputation ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [store.pushPayload](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_pushPayload) to add data to store

Comment: this. store.pushPayload  is not work when i am pushing the object

Comment: i am getting pushPayload is not an function

Comment: @niteshsingh you might be using old version of ember-data, upgrade your ember-data

Comment: i am using  ember-data.min2.2.1.js

Comment: @niteshsingh then you are doing something wrong store has `pushPayload` in ember-data 2.2.1,